# Code coverage for Mocha in Windows 7

Tags: windows, node.js, mocha.js, istanbul

I am trying to do code coverage for `mocha` using `istanbul` which I have installed globally:

I do this [as suggested here](https://github.com/nelsonic/learn-mocha)

```
  E:\Do\learn_mocha>istanbul cover _mocha -- -R spec

C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\_mocha.CMD:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @IF EXIST "%~dp0
                                                              ^
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:102:13)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at runFn (C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\comma
nd\common\run-with-cover.js:114:16)
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\command\comm
on\run-with-cover.js:232:17
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-ma
tcher.js:56:16
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-ma
tcher.js:35:9
```

This command also throws the same error as above:

```
    E:\Do\learn_mocha>istanbul cover --hook-run-in-context _mocha -- -R spec
```

I was told by a github issue that I had to add a path to mocha from `node_modules`,so I did this:

```
    E:\Do\learn_mocha>istanbul cover C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\mocha -- -R
```

spec

```
C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\mocha:2
basedir=`dirname "$0"`
        ^
No coverage information was collected, exit without writing coverage information

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\istanbul\lib\hook.js:102:13)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at runFn (C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\comma
nd\common\run-with-cover.js:114:16)
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\command\comm
on\run-with-cover.js:232:17
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-ma
tcher.js:56:16
    at C:\Users\Vamsi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\util\file-ma
tcher.js:35:9
```

I am using Windows 7 as my OS

My test looks like this:

```
var assert = require("assert"); // core module
var C = require('../cash.js');  // our module

describe('Cash Register', function(){
  describe('Module C', function(){

    it('should have a getChange Method', function(){
      assert.equal(typeof C, 'object');
      assert.equal(typeof C.getChange, 'function');
    })

    it('getChange(210,300) should equal [50,20,20]',function(){
        assert.deepEqual(C.getChange(210,300),[50,20,20]);
    })

    it('getChange(486,1000) should equal [500,10,2,2]',function(){
        assert.deepEqual(C.getChange(486,1000),[500,10,2,2]);
    })

    it('getChange(1487,10000) should equal [5000,2000,1000,500,10,2,1]',function(){
        assert.deepEqual(C.getChange(1487,10000),[5000,2000,1000,500,10,2,1]);
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

I have both mocha and istanbul installed locally (no -g on the npm install). 
I was running

```
*./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha*
```

and this came up with the error you were seeing above. I have changed this to look in the explicit local folder for mocha

```
*./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha*
```

and now everything is working great.

Please note I'm running my setup under gitbash on windows 7

Comment: The same works for Jasmine:
`istanbul cover node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine`

Comment: anyone knows what is causing this behaviour?, i could replicate in my PC as well

Comment: @Tim, `istanbul cover` takes a JavaScript file. On Linux, _mocha is just a JS file, but on Windows it's an executable batch file, which Istanbul can't handle. I'm guessing the same is true for Jasmine

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, it should work.

```
istanbul cover %APPDATA%/npm/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- -R spec
```

Comment: For some Windows 10 users, the default npm global directory is installed and configured in `%AppData%/Roaming/`

Answer (score 0):

As per this  [comment](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/13#issuecomment-18175599) in github, in windows the batch commands are not being resolved inside javascript. Hence causing the issue.

As per the suggestion, you can directly pass the javascript function for mocha to istanbul. Here is how you can do it

- Type `npm ls -g --depth=0`
- Copy the first line of the output.
  it should be `C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm`
- Type `istanbul cover C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha test\folder`

So here instead of passing the _mocha(windows command), the javascript from your global mocha installation is being passed. This is exactly what, happening for the local installation of mocha in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
istanbul cover C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\mocha\\bin\\_mocha
                          ^
                          Insert Your username here
```

Where `username` = Your username

Answer (score 0):

Try:
        istanbul cover %NODE_HOME%\node_modules\mocha\bin_mocha -- -R spec --recursive test